# Why "him" not "himself"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, pronouns, reflexives

> ***He*** felt anger rising inside ***him***.

I saw this sentence in the OED; the definition indicates that "He" and "him" refer to the same person.
Under the circumstances, "himself" is commonly seen rather than "him".
I viewed previous posts relating to this topic, but they didn't tell the same thing.

Why "him" not "himself" appears in the above sentence?
Can “him” be substituted by "himself"?

Comment: It's true there are twice as many written instances of "non-reflexive" [***felt panic rising inside him***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22felt+panic+rising+inside+him%22) as there are of [***felt panic rising inside himself***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22felt+panic+rising+inside+himself%22) (four as opposed to two). But syntactically and idiomatically I have no problem with either. It's really just a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk et al) explains:

> The basic reflexive pronoun is sometimes optional, in the sense that
> it may acceptably be replaced by the more usual 'ordinary' objective
> pronoun. The *self*-forms are chosen to supply special emphasis. [The
> scare quotes are mine, EA, and I'd say the reflexive forms are
> sometimes chosen for formality rather than emphasis]:
>
> (a) In some spatial prepositional phrases:
>
> - She's building a wall of Russian books about her(self).
> - Holding her new yellow bathrobe about her(self) with both arms, she walked up to him.
> - Mason stepped back, gently closing the door behind him(self), and walked down the corridor.
> - They left the apartment, pulling the spring lock shut behind them(selves).

With 'He felt anger rising inside him', a metaphorical (container ... level)  spatial usage, licensing 'him', 'himself' could certainly be chosen instead. However, it would sound perhaps a little ponderous, even stuffy, rather than punchy. In fact, punchier still would be 'He felt his anger rising.'